# How can I update my TextArea on button press?

Tags: java, jframe, awt

This is my code for a simple Chat GUI, I would like it so that then the user clicks on the Send Button, a change is made to the TextArea known as MessageArea.

In the ButtonPress event, If you press the Send button, it changes MessageArea, Changes the color of my panel below the MessageArea, revalidates, and repaints.

When Send it clicked, the panel does change color, but the TextArea does not change text. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

```
public class BuildWindow extends JFrame implements WindowListener, MouseListener, KeyListener {

private TextArea MessageArea    = null; //the chat window?
private TextField SendArea      = null; // where you type in your message
private String Username         = null; //username
private Button Send, Clear;
private final static String newline = "\n";
private Panel p                 = null;

BuildWindow(String s) {
    super(s);

    this.addWindowListener(this);
    this.setSize(800,600);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MessageArea = new TextArea("little test");
    MessageArea.setEditable(false);
    this.add(MessageArea, "Center");
    MessageArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));

    p = new Panel();
    p.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    SendArea = new TextField(30);
    SendArea.addKeyListener(this);
    SendArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 16));

    p.add(SendArea);
    p.setBackground(new Color(221,221,221));

    Send = new Button("Send");
    Send.addMouseListener(this);
    p.add(Send);

    Clear = new Button("Clear");
    Clear.addMouseListener(this);
    p.add(Clear);

    this.add(p, "South");
    this.setVisible(true);
    SendArea.requestFocus();
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    if (arg0.getSource() == Send) {
        MessageArea = new TextArea("TEST222");  //what i want to see change but dont
        p.setBackground(new Color(011,011,011));// what i do see change

        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
    if (arg0.getSource() == Clear) {
        //add to list
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
MessageArea.setText("TEST222");
```

instead. The line you had before,

```
MessageArea = new TextArea("TEST222");
```

creates a *brand new TextArea*. And since it's not added to a container, it's not visible. (And the old one is still visible, because you didn't do anything that would make it not visible)

Comment: You might mark this solved so folks don't waste their time looking to help where it is not needed. Also, Lachlan probably would appreciate the points. (Just a reminder!)

Answer (score 1):

1. You are mixing heavyweight (AWT) and lightweight components (Swing).  Since AWT was superseded by Swing 15+ years ago, I would suggest making use of it instead.  Replace `TextArea` with `JTextArea`.  Mixing AWT and Swing components can also cause painting issues, as AWT components don't have a concept of z-ordering. While this is "suppose" to have been fixed, I've generally found issues with it and is best simply avoided.
2. You are using a `MouseListener` on a button, this is not how buttons should be managed, I believe even in AWT, you should be using an `ActionListener`
3. You are creating a new instance of `TextArea` in the `mouseClicked` method, `MessageArea = new TextArea("TEST222");` this is not what's on the screen.  Instead, use a `JTextArea` and use it's `append` method, `messageArea.append("TEST222\n");`

Take a look at:

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [How to Write an Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)
- [How to Use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

for more details

You might like to also have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others